# Required field handling Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an application I have created in Excel VBA. This application requires a lot of entries from the user. All the fields/cells are required to have values before submission. What will be the best way to check that the users entered values in every single field/cell. I could do simple IF satatements, but that will take forever to write the tons of IFs that I will need. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use if statements. You can speed the process up by creating a helper function. This one checks for empty and numeric data only. It can be modified to look for dates and text easily

```
Function ValidCell(RowPos As Long, ColPos As Long) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim v As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    v = ws.Cells(RowPos, Colpos).Value

    If IsEmpty(v) Or Not IsNumeric(v) Then
        ValidCell = False
    Else
        ValidCell = True
    End If
End Function
```